# bind not working for required input field

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've this AngularJS HTML using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-app ng-controller="MyController">   
    <br/><br/>
    <form name="myForm">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control" ng-model="input" maxlength="{{inputMaxLength}}" ng-minlength="{{inputMaxLength}}" ng-maxlength="{{inputMaxLength}}" placeholder="Type input.." aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required />
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" ng-bind="{{inputMaxLength-input.length}}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this controller:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.input = "";
    $scope.inputMaxLength = 18;
}
```

[image]

The Bootstrap addon in the field, should always count the remaining characters. The Submit button should be disabled as long the form is not valid.

The button works as aspected, but the "count down" in the add on is always 18.

Why?

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/29m5tdsc/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in ng-min-length, you should have:

```
ng-minlength="{{inputMinLength}}"
```

instead of

```
ng-minlength="{{inputMaxLength}}"
```

Oh and you should lose the curly braces on ng-bind, you can use one or the other but not both
So either:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" ng-bind="inputMaxLength-input.length"></span>
```

or

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">{{inputMaxLength-input.length}}</span>
```

(same applies for `ng-minlength="{{inputMaxLength}}" ng-maxlength="{{inputMaxLength}}"`, no need for interpolation here, use `ng-minlength="inputMaxLength" ng-maxlength="inputMaxLength"` instead)

Note that while the input does not fulfill the requirements ie. larger than minLength and shorter than maxLength input will not have a value.
In this case you can get the value using `myForm.input.$viewValue`

I have updated you fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/29m5tdsc/9/

Comment: I do not have a `inputMinLength`. The length must be exactly 18, therefore this is used both on min and max.

Comment: I see, then you come to the second part of my answer, you cannot get the length of an invalid model using ng-model.

Comment: Then what you are trying to do is not possible. `ng-minlength` works like this: if the value is valid then update `ng-model`. if not, leave it be. So even if you `$watch` the model it won't be updated until there are 18 chars in the field.

Comment: You can just use myForm.input.$viewValue instead that will give you the input no matter what

Comment: Edited the above answer with a working fiddle as well

Answer (score 1):

This can't work : your ng-validation (ng-minlength) will set $scope.input to null. So your counter wont work.

Besides, you wrote :

```
ng-bind="{{inputMaxLength - input.length}}"
```

When angular will work he will replace variables with values. You should wrote :

```
ng-bind="(inputMaxLength - input.length)"
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1d9rcum/)